# How to link list elements from 2nd to last element in Python

Tags: python, string, list, join, vcd

I am trying to extract the time and signal change from a `.vcd` file (Value change dump) in Python for analysis.

What I got：

```
# 100 (this is the timestamp)
['0', '#', '%']
['1', '@', '!']
```

What I hope to get：

```
# 100
['0', '#%']
['1', '@!']
```

This is my code:

```
import re
fname = input("Enter filename: ")
vcd = open(fname)

for line in vcd:
    line = line.rstrip()

    if re.findall('^#', line):
            time = line
            print(time)

    elif  re.findall('^0', line) or re.findall('^1', line):
            sigVar = list(line)
            for i in sigVar[1:]:
                    ''.join(sigVar)

            print(sigVar)
```

I couldn't join the elements in sigVar together. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this :

```
>>> l = ['1','2','3']
>>> l[1:] = [''.join(l[1:])]
>>> l
['1', '23']
```